# Any way to save a graph as PDF using FusionCharts 3.1 inside a Windows Service?

Tags: asp.net, pdf, windows-services

I'm working on an asp.net website that uses FusionCharts v3.1 code to render graphs as swf files.

I need to write code to allow users to re-create and email these graphs on a scheduled basis. Our product uses a service to take care of scheduling and email events so I need to modify the code to first render the data as a graph, save it as a PDF, then attach it to the email body. All this must be done in the service so no UI will be available.

Anyone know if IE can be loaded and display a shockwave object if there's no UI available?

Answer (score 2):

This is Subhayu from the FusionCharts team. Maybe I can offer you some help. :)

Saving the charts as PDF files is as easy as cake. Check out the following link for detailed steps on how to export the charts as PDF and save it directly to the specified location.

Go to www.fusioncharts.com/docs. Using the nav bar on the left go to Exporting as Image/PDF > Server-side Exporting.

For your second query on how to just create the chart image without using any interface(without rendering it to the client side),  we have a demo on how to do exactly this in .NET 2.0. Please provide your e-mail id on this post so that we can provide this demo to you. Or you can optionally send a request to support[at]fusioncharts.com.

Hope this helps. :)